# Combine two set of same entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

**I have this class**

```
public class Subject
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string SubjectName { get; set; }

    public string Technology { get; set; }
}
```

I have two queries to select data from that class.
**Query A**

```
var subjectA = _dbContext.Subjects
                .Where(x => x.Technology == "Tech A")
                .Take(10)
                .ToList();
```

**Query B**

```
var subjectB = _dbContext.Subjects
                .Where(x => x.Technology == "Tech B")
                .Take(10)
                .ToList();
```

I need these two entities combined as one list of entity.
But, I couldn't find any example to do so.

> **EDIT**: I need 10 from each of them.

Comment: You mean you want 10 of "Tech A" or "Tech B"?

Comment: I need 10 from each of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have two lists of items and you want to combine them into a single list, you can use the [Enumerable.Concat< T>(this IEnumerable< T>, IEnumerable< T>)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method.

```
var bothSubjects = subjectA.Concat(subjectB);
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you need the first 10 of each or 10 total, no matter what?

Could be:

```
_dbContext.Subjects
  .Where(x => x.Technology == "Tech A")
  .Take(10)
  .Union(_dbContext.Subjects
          .Where(x => x.Technology == "Tech B")
          .Take(10))
  .ToList();
```

Or:

```
_dbContext.Subjects
  .Where(x => x.Technology == "Tech A" || x.Technology == "Tech B")
  .Take(10) // Or 20
  .ToList();
```

Comment: I need 10 from each of them.

Comment: Concat is better because there won't be any duplicates, so the work of Union in checking duplication is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the OR operator `||` for 10 from *either*:

```
var subjectAB = _dbContext.Subjects
                .Where(x => x.Technology == "Tech A" || x.Technology == "Tech B")
                .Take(10)
                .ToList();
```

If you want 10 from *each* then use `.Concat`:

```
var subjectAB = _dbContext.Subjects
    .Where(x => x.Technology == "Tech A")
    .Take(10)
    .Concat(_dbContext.Subjects
        .Where(x.Technology == "Tech B")
        .Take(10))
    .ToList();
```

`Concat` joins the two sequences without attempting any work to remove duplicates that `Union` does.

Comment: Also note that taking 10 is fairly meaningless unless you first order the records by a useful field.

Comment: I will be using `concat`. Its the better option for my project.
And on my actual project I am randomizing these entities and then selecting 10 of them. So, order is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if I understand your question
But if you want to do a single query to get both technologies, you could simple do:

```
var subjects = _dbContext.Subjects
                .Where(x => x.Technology == "Tech A" || x.Technology == "Tech B")
                .Take(10)
                .ToList();
```

Though I would strongly reccomend you to select the techs by their IDs, not their string names.

```
For example: .where(x => x.TechnologyId == 1 (Number of your id)

var subjects = _dbContext.Subjects
                    .Where(x => x.TechnologyId == 1 || x.TechnologyId == 2
                    .Take(10)
                    .ToList();
```

You could also Query subject A, then query subject B and sum them both. That would depend on your requirement. But if you just need both, use the first query.

Comment: The queries I used for this question were just examples. I am aware of the consequences of not using the IDs. Anyway thanks.